# In postgres how can I delete all columns that share the same prefix

Tags: postgresql

I have been using the following code for dropping all tables that share the same prefix (in this case delete all tables that their name starts with `'supenh_'`):

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   _tbl text;
BEGIN
FOR _tbl  IN
    SELECT quote_ident(table_schema) || '.'
        || quote_ident(table_name)      -- escape identifier and schema-qualify!
    FROM   information_schema.tables
    WHERE  table_name LIKE 'supenh_' || '%'  -- your table name prefix
    AND    table_schema NOT LIKE 'pg_%'     -- exclude system schemas
LOOP
  --  RAISE NOTICE '%',
   EXECUTE
  'DROP TABLE ' || _tbl;
END LOOP;
END
$do$;
```

Is there a way to amend this code / or to use a different script in order to delete from one specific table all the columns that start with the same prefix (for example, `'patient1_'`) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write it as PL/pgSQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION drop_columns_with_prefix(tbl_name TEXT, column_prefix TEXT)  RETURNS VOID AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    _column TEXT;
BEGIN
    FOR _column  IN
        SELECT quote_ident(column_name)
        FROM   information_schema.columns
        WHERE  table_name = tbl_name
        AND    column_name LIKE column_prefix || '%'
        AND    table_schema NOT LIKE 'pg_%'
    LOOP
      --  RAISE NOTICE '%',
       EXECUTE
      'ALTER TABLE ' || tbl_name || ' DROP COLUMN ' || _column;
    END LOOP;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Call it using:

```
SELECT drop_columns_with_prefix('tbl_name', 'prefix_');
```

Or if you don't want to use it as a function:

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
    _column TEXT;
BEGIN
FOR _column  IN
    SELECT quote_ident(column_name)
    FROM   information_schema.columns
    WHERE  table_name = 'tbl_name'
    AND    column_name LIKE 'prefix_%'
    AND    table_schema NOT LIKE 'pg_%'
LOOP
  --  RAISE NOTICE '%',
   EXECUTE
  'ALTER TABLE tbl_name DROP COLUMN ' || _column;
END LOOP;
END
$do$
```

Comment: Hi Bohuslav Burghardt, 
I am interested in deleting all COLUMNS that have the same prefix in a specific table (myTable1, for example) - and NOT in interested in deleting all tables that have the same prefix. The code I provided is just a code I used for deleting all tables with the same prefix, and it works well for me. The code you provided is also deleting tables - and not columns, and is not addressing my need here. If you can, please try again. Thanks!

Comment: @Roy Sorry I originally misread the question, like I said it's getting late :) ... please try the updated solution